# Sylow subgroup of $S_{11}$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I want to construct some Sylow $3$-subgroup of $S_{11}$.This subgroup has $3^4$ elements. I know any Sylow $3$-subgroup is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^3\rtimes P$ where $P$ is a Sylow $3$-subgroup of $S_3$.

But when I write $$H=\langle(123)\rangle\oplus\langle(456)\rangle\oplus\langle(789)\rangle\oplus\mathord{?}$$
why can't we find fourth direct summand? Could anyone explain this fact? Thanks.

Comment: A subgroup that permute the 3 cycles, for instance $<(147)(258)(369)>$.

Comment: yes you r right but i just want some explanation that H does not have a fourth direct summand.

Comment: An element centralizing $H$ would have to permute the elements in each of the sets $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{4,5,6\}$, $\{7,8,9\}$, $\{10,11\}$. The subgroup $\langle (1,2,3) \rangle$ is self-centralizing in $S_3$, and similarly for the other two factors. Also no element of order $3$ can permute $\{10,11\}$ non-trivially.

Comment: while trying to understand Derek, i m stuck another point: is it true that for two non disjoint commuting permutations, one must be a power of the other.

Comment: No: for example $(1,2)(3,4)$ and $(1,3)(2,4)$.